# Evaluate Irrational with Julia

Tags: constants, julia, sympy, evaluation

Julia has the built-in constant `pi`, with type `Irrational`.

```
julia> pi
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> π
π = 3.1415926535897...

julia> typeof(pi)
Irrational{:π}
```

Coming from SymPy, which has the `N()` function, I would like to evaluate `pi` (or other `Irrational`s, such as `e`, `golden`, etc.) to n digits.

```
In [5]: N(pi, n=50)
Out[5]: 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
```

Is this possible? I am assuming that `pi` is based on its mathematical definition, rather than just to thirteen decimal places.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, you can set the `BigFloat` precision and use `big(π)`. Note that the precision is binary; it's counted in bits. You should be safe if you set the precision to at least `log2(10) + 1` times the number of digits you need.

Example:

```
julia> setprecision(BigFloat, 2000) do
           @printf "%.200f" big(π)
       end
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937510582097494459230781640628620899862803482534211706798214808651328230664709384460955058223172535940812848111745028410270193852110555964462294895493038196
```

Here I've set the precision a little higher than it needs to be for just 200 digits.

The digits are computed in the GNU MPFR library.

Comment: Works perfectly. I seem to be able to use `Int(ceil((log2(10))n))` for perfect, precision, too! (Replaces the need for the `+1` and extra computation.)

Answer (score 10):

Julia has an interface for the [SymPy package](https://github.com/jverzani/SymPy.jl):

```
# Pkg.add("SymPy")  ## initial installation of package
using SymPy
julia> N(PI, 50)
3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937508
```

Note that SymPy uses the uppercase `PI` to distinguish it's object from the lowercase `pi` in native Julia.  You'll also need the native SymPy installed on your computer to get full functionality here.

Other comments:

- see [here](https://github.com/jverzani/SymPy.jl/blob/master/examples/tutorial.md) for a longer tutorial on Julia SymPy with a lot of good examples.